# Exception handing in kernel module

Tags: exception, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04, kernel-module

In my Linux 3.16 module code, at some point, I want to go to the error handling routine, e.g. `do_invalid_op` [[Linux codeline](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L313)]. By directly calling `do_invalid_op` in a kernel module, it would immediately crash the entire Linux system, even without a trace in `/var/log/kern.log` (for me to debug). For instance,

```
void module_begin(){
    ...
    if(error_found){
        do_invalid_op(reg, error_code); //expected to return control to user space without running "a=1" line.
    }
    int a = 1;
    ...
}

module_init(module_begin());
```

My general question is how to convert to error handling code (interrupt handler) in a kernel module?

Update 1: The sample code is updated to reflect the things I intend the module to do; once a `error_found`, the kernel execution should jump to somewhere (e.g. user space) without running rest of the module init code.

Update 2: Trace information about the crash, hope it's helpful

```
Entering the yyy!
Meaning of life: 41
Value of tcs: 0x19e5010
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 304369                             /home/tom/workspace/coding/xxx-emulator-v2/TR/client/bin/a.out
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:01 304369                             /home/tom/workspace/coding/xxx-emulator-v2/TR/client/bin/a.out
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 304369                             /home/tom/workspace/coding/xxx-emulator-v2/TR/client/bin/a.out
019e5000-01a07000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f767aed5000-7f767aed6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 304337                     /home/tom/workspace/coding/xxx-emulator-v2/TR/client/bin/yyy.so
7f767aed6000-7f767b0d5000 ---p 00001000 08:01 304337                     /home/tom/workspace/coding/xxx-emulator-v2/TR/client/bin/yyy.so
7f767b0d5000-7f767b0d6000 r--p 00000000 08:01 304337                     /home/tom/workspace/coding/xxx-emulator-v2/TR/client/bin/yyy.so
7f767b0d6000-7f767b0d7000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 304337                     /home/tom/workspace/coding/xxx-emulator-v2/TR/client/bin/yyy.so
7f767b0d7000-7f767b292000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 791296                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f767b292000-7f767b492000 ---p 001bb000 08:01 791296                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f767b492000-7f767b496000 r--p 001bb000 08:01 791296                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f767b496000-7f767b498000 rw-p 001bf000 08:01 791296                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f767b498000-7f767b49d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f767b49d000-7f767b4a0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 791313                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f767b4a0000-7f767b69f000 ---p 00003000 08:01 791313                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f767b69f000-7f767b6a0000 r--p 00002000 08:01 791313                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f767b6a0000-7f767b6a1000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 791313                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
7f767b6a1000-7f767b6c4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 791272                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f767b8aa000-7f767b8ad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f767b8c0000-7f767b8c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f767b8c3000-7f767b8c4000 r--p 00022000 08:01 791272                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f767b8c4000-7f767b8c5000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 791272                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f767b8c5000-7f767b8c6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff85cb4000-7fff85cd5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff85ce5000-7fff85ce7000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7fff85ce7000-7fff85ce9000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
note: sections in order: .text, .rodata, .bss 
Inside Enclave now 
Killed


@dmesg
[   87.913346] Local XXX Handler Called from PID: 2877 EIP: 0x    400bfd
[   87.913349] Hooked an EENTER instruction.
[   87.913350] TT: Done hooking EENTER: rbx:00000000019e5010, rdx:00000000019e6020 
[   87.913353] Syscall inside Enclave hooked! NR=1, i=5 
[   87.913355]   Caller process: pid: 2877, tid: 2877, comm: a.out, 
[   87.913355]                           uid: 1000, gid: 1000, euid: 18446744069414585320 
[   87.913355]                           suid: 140144782869480, sgid: 1000, fsuid: 140144782869480, fsgid: 1000, user: 1000, 
[   87.913357]   Caller context: ret_addr: 00007f767b8aa740, filename to open():/proc/self/maps
[   87.913360] Syscall inside Enclave hooked! NR=2, i=6 
[   87.913362]   Caller process: pid: 2877, tid: 2877, comm: a.out, 
[   87.913362]                           uid: 1000, gid: 1000, euid: 18446612132314219496 
[   87.913362]                           suid: 18446744069414585320, sgid: 1000, fsuid: 1000, fsgid: 1000, user: 140144782869480, 
[   87.913364]   Caller context: ret_addr: 00007fff85cd35e8, filename to open():temp.txt
[   87.913378] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[   87.913380] Modules linked in: xxx(OE) nls_utf8 isofs vboxsf(OE) snd_intel8x0 snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event hid_generic snd_rawmidi joydev snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer usbhid hid snd rfcomm bnep bluetooth 6lowpan_iphc serio_raw vboxvideo(OE) i2c_piix4 vboxguest(OE) soundcore drm parport_pc mac_hid ppdev lp parport psmouse ahci libahci e1000 pata_acpi
[   87.913401] CPU: 0 PID: 2877 Comm: a.out Tainted: G           OE 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[   87.913402] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[   87.913404] task: ffff88002cf67010 ti: ffff88002bd94000 task.ti: ffff88002bd94000
[   87.913405] RIP: 03e8:[<ffffffffc01d342a>]  [<ffffffffc01d342a>] hook+0x12a/0x134 [xxx]
[   87.913409] RSP: 03e8:00000000000003e8  EFLAGS: ffffffff000003e8
[   87.913410] RAX: 0000000000000049 RBX: ffff88002cf67010 RCX: 0000000000000006
[   87.913411] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000046 RDI: 0000000000000246
[   87.913412] RBP: ffff88002bd97f50 R08: 0000000000000082 R09: 0000000000000214
[   87.913413] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff88002bd97c2e R12: 0000000000000241
[   87.913414] R13: 00000000000001b6 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[   87.913416] FS:  00007f767b8aa740(0000) GS:ffff88003fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   87.913417] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   87.913419] CR2: 00007f767b24eee4 CR3: 0000000036cb7000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
[   87.913423] Stack:
[   87.913426] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 00000000000003e8
[   87.913428] IP: [<ffffffff81015a29>] show_stack_log_lvl+0x109/0x180
[   87.913434] PGD 3ab9a067 PUD 2ed84067 PMD 0 


[   87.913437] Oops: 0000 [#2] SMP 
[   87.913438] Modules linked in: xxx(OE) nls_utf8 isofs vboxsf(OE) snd_intel8x0 snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event hid_generic snd_rawmidi joydev snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer usbhid hid snd rfcomm bnep bluetooth 6lowpan_iphc serio_raw vboxvideo(OE) i2c_piix4 vboxguest(OE) soundcore drm parport_pc mac_hid ppdev lp parport psmouse ahci libahci e1000 pata_acpi
[   87.913452] CPU: 0 PID: 2877 Comm: a.out Tainted: G           OE 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[   87.913453] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[   87.913454] task: ffff88002cf67010 ti: ffff88002bd94000 task.ti: ffff88002bd94000
[   87.913455] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff81015a29>]  [<ffffffff81015a29>] show_stack_log_lvl+0x109/0x180
[   87.913457] RSP: 0018:ffff88002bd97c60  EFLAGS: 00010046
[   87.913458] RAX: 00000000000003f0 RBX: 00000000000003e8 RCX: 0000000000000000
[   87.913459] RDX: ffff88003fc03fc0 RSI: ffff88002bd97e88 RDI: 0000000000000000
[   87.913460] RBP: ffff88002bd97cb0 R08: ffff88003fbfffc0 R09: 0000000000000224
[   87.913461] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff88002bd979de R12: ffff88002bd97e88
[   87.913462] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffffff81a64864 R15: 0000000000000000
[   87.913464] FS:  00007f767b8aa740(0000) GS:ffff88003fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   87.913465] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   87.913466] CR2: 00000000000003e8 CR3: 0000000036cb7000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
[   87.913466] Stack:
[   87.913467]  ffffffff8175b59b ffff880000000008 ffff88002bd97cc0 ffff88002bd97c80
[   87.913469]  00000000000003e8 ffff88002bd97e88 00000000000003e8 0000000000000040
[   87.913471]  0000000000000000 0000000000000006 ffff88002bd97cf0 ffffffff81015b2a
[   87.913473] Call Trace:
[   87.913478]  [<ffffffff8175b59b>] ? printk+0x67/0x69
[   87.913480]  [<ffffffff81015b2a>] show_regs+0x8a/0x200
[   87.913482]  [<ffffffff810169bf>] __die+0x9f/0xe0
[   87.913484]  [<ffffffff81016e48>] die+0x38/0x70
[   87.913486]  [<ffffffff81013400>] do_trap+0xb0/0x150
[   87.913489]  [<ffffffff81013ac7>] do_error_trap+0x97/0x150
[   87.913491]  [<ffffffffc01d342a>] ? hook+0x12a/0x134 [xxx]
[   87.913496]  [<ffffffff810c8bb4>] ? wake_up_klogd+0x34/0x50
[   87.913498]  [<ffffffff810c8dc8>] ? console_unlock+0x1f8/0x440
[   87.913500]  [<ffffffff81014140>] do_invalid_op+0x20/0x30
[   87.913503]  [<ffffffffc01d32f2>] intr_handler+0x12/0x20 [xxx]
[   87.913505]  [<ffffffffc01d3465>] intr_stub+0x15/0x20 [xxx]
[   87.913507]  [<ffffffffc01d342a>] ? hook+0x12a/0x134 [xxx]
[   87.913509]  [<ffffffffc01d3493>] new_sys_open+0x23/0x40 [xxx]
[   87.913512]  [<ffffffff8176aced>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[   87.913513] Code: 4d b8 4c 89 45 c0 48 89 55 c8 48 8b 5b f8 e8 23 5b 74 00 48 8b 55 c8 4c 8b 45 c0 8b 4d b8 85 c9 74 05 f6 c1 03 74 4c 48 8d 43 08 <48> 8b 33 48 c7 c7 5c 48 a6 81 89 4d b4 4c 89 45 b8 48 89 45 c8 
[   87.913531] RIP  [<ffffffff81015a29>] show_stack_log_lvl+0x109/0x180
[   87.913534]  RSP <ffff88002bd97c60>
[   87.913535] CR2: 00000000000003e8
[   87.913537] ---[ end trace 38675fa903317736 ]---
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is very unusual and it is not at all surprising that it crashes the OS.

Interrupt handlers are not meant to be called directly from other code. For one thing, they do not return in the way that an ordinary C function returns. On x86, interrupt handlers return with a `RETI` instruction, which expects to find saved register values on the stack. (That cannot be done in C and requires assembly language code. See `arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S` to see the low-level interrupt handling and return code for x86-32.) If you try to call into an interrupt handler from other C code, when the handler returns, it will take whatever "junk" it finds on the stack and load that into your registers, including the stack pointer and instruction pointer.

If you explain why you want to do this, perhaps someone can help you find an alternative way to accomplish what you actually want to accomplish.

**EDIT:**

I thought you were calling directly into an interrupt handler, but now I see that `do_invalid_op` is just a C function which is called from the interrupt handler. However, why are you calling it with no args? Here is how it is defined in edge Linux:

```
#define DO_ERROR(trapnr, signr, str, name)              \
dotraplinkage void do_##name(struct pt_regs *regs, long error_code) \
{                                   \
    do_error_trap(regs, error_code, str, trapnr, signr);        \
}

DO_ERROR(X86_TRAP_UD,     SIGILL,  "invalid opcode",        invalid_op)
```

So you have to pass 2 args, a `struct pt_regs*` and `long`. Does it still crash if you do that?

Comment: seems reasonable. looks like BOTH entry and return of interrupt handler have to go through asm/register manipulation... got it. 

The thing I want to do is to just call the code inside `do_invalid_op()` (without `RETI` instruction in the end though...)

Comment: good edit. what I actually called is `invalid_op()` (the no-argument version of `do_invalid_op(...)` )... and it still crashes

Comment: The first part of my answer addresses that one. `invalid_op` is the interrupt vector. You can't call that directly from C.

Comment: look at [[here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/traps.h#L21)], `invalid_op` is a function

Comment: it's also revealed as function in kernel symbol table... same with `do_valid_op`.

Comment: It's defined in a C header, so it can be passed to `set_intr_gate`. But that doesn't mean you can call it from just anywhere. Look at the implementation in `arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S`.

Comment: Yes, tried to use do_invalid_op with argument. The argument is the reg values right before calling do_invalid_op. I have updated OP with crash trace data.

Comment: It looks like what you passed in the `regs` argument is faulty.